# Byte Buddy Member Substitution throwing IllegalStateException error

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I'm trying to write a java instrumentation agent using byte buddy. My goal is to replace a java standard library method call with a proxy call of my own. I was suggested to use Byte Buddy's `MemberSubstitution` to achieve this. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637694/use-of-bytebuddys-membersubstitution-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808499/can-a-method-call-be-instrumented-with-bytebuddy-instead-of-the-called-method?rq=1) questions from SO for my reference.

I'm using Intellij IDEA for coding. My Agent code is split into multiple files as follows:

**MyFirstAgent.java**

```
public class MyFirstAgent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(ElementMatchers.any())
                .transform(new ByteBuddyTransformer())
                .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())
                .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
                .installOn(inst);
}
```

**ByteBuddyTransformer.java**

```
public class ByteBuddyTransformer implements AgentBuilder.Transformer {

    @Override
    public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                                            ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {

        try {
            return builder.visit(MemberSubstitution.relaxed()
                    .method(named("add"))
                    .replaceWith(MyClass.class.getMethod("printLine"))
                    .on(any()));

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return builder;
    }
}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {
    public boolean printLine(){
        System.out.println("This is the proxy!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the application that I want to instrument is in another Intellij IDEA project with the following:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassToMonitor classToMonitor = new ClassToMonitor();
        classToMonitor.bar();
    }
}
```

**ClassToMonitor.java**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ClassToMonitor {
    public void bar() {
// create an empty array list with an initial capacity
        ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

// use add() method to add elements in the list
        arrlist.add(15);

// print all the elements available in list
        for (Integer number : arrlist) {
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the fat jar of my agent and run it with my application, I get the following error:

```
[Byte Buddy] ERROR com.company.ClassToMonitor [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2626b418, unnamed module @385e9564, loaded=false]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke public boolean com.company.MyClass.printLine() on [class java.util.ArrayList, E]
```

I can provide the full error message if required. Also, I'm new to Java and Instrumentation in general so I might be missing something fundamental here, please kindly excuse me and point it out if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

For substitution to work, the target method needs to accept the same arguments as the replaced method, in your case an `int`. Also, since you are calling a member, the implicit first argument of your class needs to be the receiver type, i.e. `ArrayList` or any super type, even `Object`. Also, your replacement method needs to be static:

```
public class MyClass {
  public static boolean printLine(Object ignored, int ignored2){
    System.out.println("This is the proxy!");
    return true;
  }
}
```

MemberSubstitution is still not as flexible as it is supposed to be. You can however already inject custom byte code using the `chained` step if that is what you want.